# Can't import VecFrameStackFrame from Stable-baselines3 - importing problem

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, reinforcement-learning, stable-baselines

I have a problem when importing some dependencies from stable baselines 3 library, I installed it with this command

```
pip install stable-baselines3[extra]
```

But When I import my dependencies

```
import gym
from stable_baselines3 import A2C
from stable_baselines3.common.vec_env import VecFrameStackFrame
from stable_baselines3.common.evaluation import evaluate_policy
from stable_baselines3.common.env_util import make_atari_env
import os
```

I face this error

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'VecFrameStackFrame' from 'stable_baselines3.common.vec_env' (C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\rl_learning\lib\site-packages\stable_baselines3\common\vec_env\__init__.py)
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I knew that stable baselines new version has changed the name from

```
from stable_baselines3.common.vec_env import VecFrameStackFrame
```

To

```
from stable_baselines3.common.vec_env import vec_frame_stack
```

and it worked for me